# How to download and play xbox games offline

Tags: xbox-360

Guys,

My friend has one Xbox 360. But he has small internet connection in his home. But, he want to buy games online and download in to the xbox 360. Problem is the internet. So, He can buy and download games from my home.

Is there have any option to download or redeem games from the store to a portable/cloud drive. Then use on xbox 360.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you get him to bring his Xbox to your house, and let him buy and download the games straight onto his Xbox (using your internet connection). That will probably be easiest.

Comment: @joejoe31b Yes we did it. but, he is in so far to my home. Everyday he can't do that. I suppose there have one option do it offline.

Comment: You want to download games without an internet connection? I'm afraid that's just not going to work.

Comment: Why does he need to download games everyday? How many games does he get through per day? I'd imagine he can download a few games which should occupy his time for 1 month or so before he needs to get another batch. Going through a few games a day just sound crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing for Xbox 360 is complicated, and Microsoft changes it at their whim.  Thus, before you follow any advice, I'd suggest [reading the current Microsoft support document.](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/downloadable-content/download-content)  You might have to click around to get to the one for your country/region, as the rules change per region.  I'd also suggest testing any method with some cheap or free DLC before you commit large sums of money.

With that disclaimer out of the way, here's the solution.

You've got two Xbox 360s in this scenario.

- Xbox 360 #1 is the one with the good internet connection
- Xbox 360 #2 is the one with the bad internet connection

Your friend visits your house where Xbox #1 is.  He [downloads his Xbox Live profile](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/profile-move-delete) on the box, which adds his account to your Xbox.  He [plugs a USB key](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive) into the Xbox.  He then buys and downloads his DLC onto the USB key using his account on your box.

Then he goes home to his box, #2.  Here he can plug the USB key in, and log into his account online.  The Xbox will check his account to make sure he has permission to play the game (which doesn't require as much bandwidth as downloading the game).  Then he *should* be able to play his game on his Xbox.

Comment: Adding to that. You download the demo to Xbox#1 then copy to USB, then to his Xbox. He downloads the file and because it is already on the Xbox it will only have to download 2-18%. If not go from 1%-100% download complete. Meaning if it's a demo and he buys it online(or games for gold) when he is on his Xbox it will register to his Xbox allowing offline play also.